# Is there a way to force an app into tablet mode on a phone?

Tags: tablet, screen-resolution

I have been regularly using a Mackie DL1608 digital mixer lately, and am a bit frustrated by the fact that I cannot get the full functionality of their Master Fader 5 app on my phone. When doing something more serious I usually use a tablet, but there are times, when it would be more convenient to be able to access the full UI from my phone.

So far I have tried:

- Adjusting the `Smallest width` value in developer options
- Modifying the `ro.sf.lcd_density` prop
- Setting the resolution / DPI through `App Settings Reborn`

But none of these have worked. The UI gets smaller (more channels visible at the same time), but doesn't show the missing controls. I have also tried setting the display size of a tablet in the opposite direction, and interestingly enough, that triggered the switch to the phone layout. Does anyone know of other methods that are used to tell phones and tablets apart in apps, and maybe methods to fool them? One more thing I noticed is that the Play Store only shows screenshots of the mobile layout when I'm viewing it from my phone.

---

*Edit: For future reference, in case anyone finds this post, who is in a similar situation, I am also considering using `Mixing Station` as an alternative, as well as reverse engineering the protocol myself.*

Comment: Typically apps don't differ between phone and tablet. What is shown is determined by the display, thus the display resolution and it's pixel density (using both you can calculate the real display size which works on most devices).